# How can I convert this query into a rawQuery in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-like

This is the query that I need to convert to a rawQuery in Android Studio:

select EVENT from U7toU16Events where EVENT_CODE like 'U14%' into a rawQuery (Similar like operator examples: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

The number '14' is a string variable called 'communityGamesAge' that can be any number from 5 to 16.

I tried this but my syntax is wrong:

c = db.rawQuery("select EVENT from U7toU16Events where EVENT_CODE like 'U"+communityGamesAge+"%'", new String[]{});

This is my code

'''
//method to query db and return a result

```
public String getEvents(String communityGamesAge){

    c = db.rawQuery("select EVENT from U7toU16Events where EVENT_CODE like 'U"+communityGamesAge+"%'", new String[]{});

    //c = db.rawQuery("select EVENT from U7toU16Events where EVENT_CODE like 'U14%'", new String[]{});

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    while (c.moveToNext()){
        String event = c.getString(1);
        buffer.append(" * ").append(event).append("\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

'''

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please supply logs from logcat. What exactly you are getting in error.

Comment: why `rawQuery` and not `query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating the parameters is never a good idea and it is not recommended mostly for safety reasons.

Use a `?` placeholder for the parameter in the sql statement and pass the parameter `communityGamesAge` in the array of the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`:

```
c = db.rawQuery("select EVENT from U7toU16Events where EVENT_CODE like 'U' || ? || '%'", new String[] {communityGamesAge});
```